# qmp-shell doesn’t recognize commands

Tags: qemu

So, there is a python script that allows to connect to QEMU monitor from a usual shell. I had to download [a bunch of files from the QEMU source tree](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=tree;f=scripts/qmp;hb=HEAD), and add `-qmp unix:./qmp-sock,server,nowait` to the vm command line. It connects, but I can’t get it working.

```
$ qmp-shell qmp-sock 
Welcome to the QMP low-level shell!
Connected to QEMU 1.5.3

(QEMU) help
{u'error': {u'class': u'CommandNotFound', u'desc': u'The command help has not been found'}}
(QEMU) query-
query-balloon               query-fdsets                query-status
query-block                 query-kvm                   query-target
query-block-jobs            query-machines              query-tpm
query-blockstats            query-mice                  query-tpm-models
query-chardev               query-migrate               query-tpm-types
query-command-line-options  query-migrate-cache-size    query-uuid
query-commands              query-migrate-capabilities  query-version
query-cpu-definitions       query-name                  query-vnc
query-cpus                  query-pci                   
query-events                query-spice                 
(QEMU) query-kvm
{u'return': {u'enabled': True, u'present': True}}
(QEMU) info block
Error while parsing command line: list index out of range
command format: <command-name>  [arg-name1=arg1] ... [arg-nameN=argN]
(QEMU) info
{u'error': {u'class': u'CommandNotFound', u'desc': u'The command info has not been found'}}
(QEMU) exit
{u'error': {u'class': u'CommandNotFound', u'desc': u'The command exit has not been found'}}
(QEMU)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `qmp-shell` works the same way as, say, telneting to QMP socket and sending JSON commands directly, you need to issue the `qmp_capabilities` command.
None of the other commands in `qmp` will work until it has been executed, and will result in the 'CommandNotFound' error quoted.

See qemu wiki page regarding [QMP](http://wiki.qemu.org/QMP#Capabilities_Negotiation) for details.

Comment: That was a wrong assumption. qmp-shell does negotiation by itself. Moreover, as you could see above, some commands do work, e.g. `device_add driver=e1000 id=net1` prints `{u'return': {}}` and `quit` closes virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for that additional information @tijagi about qmp-shell doing the negotiation. The details of the return codes from "device_add" and "quit" commands weren't present in the original post though. It might be worth adding those additional details.

Comment: There’s a query-kvm command, that works as well as device_add in this case.